# Tutorials on Java Media Framework

Tags: java, video-capture, jmf

My main goal is to capture video to a data source and place it on the web.

I've spent almost eight hours looking for information on JMF. I have found a lot of information on the JMF structure and learned a lot from the API guide and bloggers, but the examples I've seen and tried to implement didn't work for me. They were either to advanced or the source code didn’t compile I learn best by examples and manipulating the examples.

So I was wondering:

1. Where did you learn how to implement the Java Media Framework into you're project(s)?
2. Can you provide some links to good examples (maybe something that is step-by-step)?

Places I’ve tried and fail:

- [Minimalist Example of Video Capture Using Java](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Java_Video_Capture.aspx) - Code Project
- [Java SE Desktop Technologies (JMF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) - OTN
- [Java Media Framework basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jmf/) - IBM
- [JMF Tutorial (PDF)](http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/tutorial/jmf_tutorial.pdf)
- [Capture Video from Logitech QuickCam Pro 3000
  Camera with Java JMF](http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/)
- Java for Programmers (2<sup>nd</sup> edition) Deitel developer series (book)
- Starting out with Java: Early Objects (book)
- Java for dummies

Comment: *"Where did you learn how to implement the JMF"*  Well, I mostly learned it while visiting ***2001***.  You do realize that JMF is both very old *and* abandoned, right?

Comment: As an aside, JMF can do everything now that it could do in 'the old days' (which was quite a lot of things, in a limited range of codecs/supported file types).  It might well be able to perform your simple task (at a maximum 640x480 resolution), but an abandoned API is not the place for a newbie to be starting.  An alternative might be [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/).

Comment: thanks did think to look for other options i just took the first thing that was mentioned i just got a Ebook on beginning javafx and will take a few hours to look at it

Answer (score 1):

In [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/JMF.htm) you can find sample JMF applications.

Also [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2001/jw-0406-jmf1.html) have a nice tutorial, which although it is old it is fairly useful.

Comment: *"although it is old it is fairly useful."*  When JMF "isn't getting any newer", is there any point in updating the tutorial? ;)